# QString equivalent of .at() C++ QT

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to run the line:

```
out.push_back( a.at(0) );
```

Where out is a QVector holding integers

```
QVector <int> out ( 0 );
```

The error code that it gives me is:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QVector<int>::push_back(const QChar)'
                 out.push_back( a.at(0) );
                                        ^
```

Which makes me believe that the .at() isn't returning the integer from that spot in the QString a, but instead the const QChar.

Is there any way that I can have it return that integer, or a better QString function that I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### What's wrong?

Your `a`  is a **`QString`**, and it's member function [`QString::at()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#at) always return `QChar`. As far as I remember, the `std::string::at()` in C++ returns `char` too rather than `int`. The data types in C++/Qt must be treated carefully!

Therefore, the returned `QChar` needs to be translated into `int` first in order to meet the type of your `QVector<int>` template.

But no worries, `QChar` has a member function for it: [**`QChar::digitValue`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qchar.html#digitValue)
(*Returns the numeric value of the digit, or **-1** if the character is not a digit.*)

---

### Solution:

Try     `out.push_back(a.at(0).digitValue());` instead.